# O WebSQL é a única forma de armazenamento local no phonegap/cordova?

Tags: apache-cordova, sqlite, websql, persistência

Fora o banco criado pelo "navegador", quais outras formas de persistência de dados nós temos no android com o phonegap?

Comment: https://github.com/knadh/localStorageDB/ Experimenta esse projeto em javascript!

Answer (score 1):

O local storage do html5 também é uma boa pedida. Uso direto para gravar informações do usuário, configurações do app e etc. Ele é um "chave valor" armazenado no browser sem tempo para expirar. Se quiser saber mais sobre... http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp Espero ter ajudado :)